# Property change notification when property members change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Say I have a property named `Location` of type `Point` in my ViewModel, to which my View binds. I'm using MVVM Light's `ObservableObject` and `RaisePropertyChanged` setup to raise property change notifications. The problem is that when I execute the following in the ViewModel:

```
this.Location = new Point(100,100);
```

my View updates correctly. But if I do:

```
this.Location.Offset(10,10);
```

my View doesn't update, means the `Location` property does not notify the View about the change. Why is this so? How do sub-properties of built-in types such as `Point` or `Size` deal with change notification?

Comment: DepedencyProperties don't belong in ViewModels.

Comment: That said, `Point` is a `struct`. You can't just change its values and expect anything. Replace the entire `Point` for a new `Point`.

Comment: @dotNET You should not use dependency properties in view models. There is no reason to do that. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead.

Comment: @Clemens: Hmm... Actually I'm not using `DependencyProperty` in my VM. Those are just normal properties, with a MVVM Light's `ObservableObject` and `RaisePropertyChanged` setup. But the problem at hand still remains unsolved; my normal property is of type `Point` and I have no way of knowing if someone has assigned a value to a member of `Point` structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that `Point` is mutable.

You could write your own `ImmutablePoint` that allows conversion to and from the existing Point class for API compatibility, but doesn't allow methods like `Offset`.

It's not an ideal solution, but it gets around the problem of changing the fields on a property rather than the property itself.

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM land, your ViewModel is responsible for notifying the View when properties change. The majority of the .NET classes do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` themselves, so you won't get automatic wiring when using them. You'll have to raise `PropertyChanged` yourself on the `Location` property each time you modify any properties of `Location`

Alternatively, you could implement your own `Point` object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: *You'll have to raise PropertyChanged yourself on the Location property each time you modify any properties of Location.* How do I do that? Means what in the world tells me if a property inside the Point structure has changed (unless I implement my own `Point` of course)?

Comment: @dotNET It means you either write your own implementation of the class that does track changes, or you manually go through your code base and find everywhere the property is modified and add code to handle raising the property changed event.  Hopefully it's clear which method is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can add INotifyPropertyChanged to your class members automatically using either Castle Dynamic Proxy (which wraps your models in a proxy at runtime) or PropertyChanged.Fody (which modifies the model's IL at compile time). Google is your friend.